# Vs2019 cannot run NUnit Tests - Issue with 'testhost.x86.exe'

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, nunit, visual-studio-2019

I am created a selenium test framework using NUnit have have a test to open a pages and assert the page title.

However, when I try to run the test, its seems to start and stop without doing anything even running with Debug. The test remains in the `not run` state.

When I put a break point on `{` and run the test with debug, nothing changes. It starts and instantly stops without running the test.

**Test:**

```
[Test]
[TestCase(Browser.Chrome)]
public void ValidateWebDriverLaunches(Browser browser)
{
    Driver = StaticWebDriverFactory.GetLocalWebDriver(browser);
    Driver.Url = "https://example.com/";

    string title = Driver.Title;
    Assert.AreEqual(true, title.Contains("Example Domain"), "Title is not matching");
}
```

**Error Log**

```
'testhost.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 2): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
'testhost.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Dependency finder domain): Unloaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll'
The thread 0xcc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'testhost.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 3): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
'testhost.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Dependency finder domain): Unloaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll'
The thread 0x2f90 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2f80 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[8948] testhost.x86.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I have set the environment variable

`__UNITTESTEXPLORER_VSINSTALLPATH__`

to point to

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE`

as some people have suggested. The only other suggestions I have found is updating VS17, however I am using VS19 and cannot find any information on this version.

Comment: Which version of VS2019 are you using?

Comment: Huh, "The program '[8948] testhost.x86.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)." According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) MS Doc page error code 0 is "ERROR_SUCCESS" and indicates success.

Comment: @MindSwipe. I am using version 16.3.0. That's strange as the test doesn't seem to run. I don't get a test success or failure in the test explorer.

Comment: Weird, do you have ReSharper installed? Also, can you try right clicking your solution and cleaning then rebuilding it? And after that try putting a breakpoint in your test method and running the UniTests in Debug mode

Comment: @MindSwipe I don't have ReSharper. I have put a break point on the `{` and the test doesn't stop at the break point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figure out that the issue was myself.

I installed `NUnit3TestAdapter` nuget package and it works as expected now.

Answer (score 3):

It is required to switch process architecture in Visual Studio to 64.

Visual Studio: Test Tab -> Process Architecture for AnyCPU Projects -> **64**

Answer (score 1):

My issue was really weird, my connection string in AppConfig was above the , moving it below solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

On the way to getting a solution, I found this tip to help see what the premature exit happens:

Go to Test/Options and set the Logging level to "Trace (includes platform logs).

In the trace, it said "NUnit failed to load c:\...\netcoreapp3.1   from a nuget package reference. The very next step from the NUnit Test Adapter 3.16.1 logged Test Execution Complete, even though no tests were run. Could it be our Nuget pacakage doesn't include netcore?  Will post back

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, I tried running UT and it did not start, and in the Output window all I saw was the above error.
The way I solved the problem:
[image]

And then check if your project is checked in build field, if not- mark it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I used NUint 3.13.3 and NUnit3 TestAdapter 4.3.0, I re-Installed NUint 3.13.2 and NUnit3 TestAdapter 4.2.1 and then after cleaning and re-building solution, the problem was solved.